# Spring JUnit testing with @Autowired annotation

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

I´m having issues with my test cases after having introduced @Autowired in one of the classes under test.

My testcase now looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext.xml", "/spring-security.xml"})
public class StudentRepositoryTest extends AbstractDatabaseTestCase {

private StudentRepository studentRepository;
private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
private Student testStudent;
private Company testCompany;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    studentRepository = new StudentRepository();
    studentRepository.setJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate());
    testStudent = Utils.testStudentNoApplication();
}
@Test
....
```

}

StudentRepository now looks like this:

```
@Service
public class StudentRepository extends AbstractRepository<Student> {

...

private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private MailService mailService;

public StudentRepository() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Autowired 
public StudentRepository(MailService mailService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.mailService = mailService;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}
```

Obviously this test case won´t work anymore. 
But what changes do I need to make to the testcase for the @Autowired annotation to be picked up by the test case?

EDIT:

I´ve now updated my setUp() to this (I need the password encoder to avoid null password):

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    //studentRepository = new StudentRepository();
    studentRepository = new StudentRepository(mock(MailService.class), ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(ShaPasswordEncoder.class));
    studentRepository.setJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate());
    testStudent = Utils.testStudentNoApplication();
}
```

My testcase is now running OK, but my testsuite failes with a NullPointerException.
I´m guessing the ApplicationContext is not being Autowired when running the testsuite for some reason?

Comment: Is this only a problem in the test? Does Spring fail in some way with an Exception?

Comment: If it's a unit test, you should probably pass mock MailService and PasswordEncoder instances to the constructor of your StudentRepository. Check out Mockito, EasyMock or any other mocking API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to declare your `StudentRepository` in one of XML files referenced by `@ContextConfiguration` and autowire it into the test, you can try to use `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` as follows:

```
...
public class StudentRepositoryTest extends AbstractDatabaseTestCase {
    ...
    @Autowired ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        studentRepository = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                               .createBean(StudentRepository.class);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, or atleast works better. I run into a new exception (UnsatisfiedDependency), but as JB Nizet mentioned in a comment above, I should probably pass mocks to the constructor.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, my solution assumes that `MailService` and `PasswordEncoder` are declared in configs referenced by `@ContextConfiguration` and you want to test against them. If you need mocks instead, use mocks.

Comment: Some success, but still some issues. I´ve updated my first post.

Comment: Turned out I was using JUnit3 style tests in the testsuit, which doesn´t detect annotations in the test classes.